# What is the "so" in "I love you so"?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

> I love you so.

What does this *so* mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is short for "so much, " and means "very much."

Answer (score -2):

so (adj.)

In the condition or manner expressed or indicated.

Comment: Not a possible meaning without a following object

Comment: How is it not a possible meaning? That's the defintion in the dictionary for the usage. The synonym of which is "thus".

Comment: That definition refers to uses like *position the pieces just so*

Comment: The problem is that there is no condition or manner expressed or indicated, which is why this is not a possible meaning.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. My mistake. Found out it's an "intensifier".